# In Flutter how to create a list of months in a dropdown list

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I am very new to Flutter Development. I am Creating a calendar using table_calendar 3.0.0 package from pub.dev(https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar). I want to create a list of months using a dropdown button in the header part. The selected month should show the corresponding dates in the calendar. will it be possible? if it possible please help me any experts. Thank u and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a list of months using a dropdown button in the header part but if you want to custom any package, make sure that you understand code inside !